# C# Network stream client server limits

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, client-server

A question for those who have worked extensively with .Net to create client/server applications.

I have put together a simple test involving a server and client application for a load test.  The client makes 500 connections to my server in a parallel loop and listens to incoming messages.  The server accepts each connection, creates a connection object for each one and each of these fires a 250ms timer to send 5000 bytes over the network stream.  Pretty simple stuff.

However, it hits errors and meltdown pretty quickly.  First sign of trouble is on one of the client connections:
**SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**

The second error received is usually the server side, with the attempts to send starting to fail during `NetworkStream.Write`.
**System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'**

My question is this:  my server is just writing data almost continually to a set of network streams associated with sockets and after a certain number of sockets (client connections) this seems to melt down.  Does anybody know why, or of any limits that apply here?

Test is being conducted on a single powerful machine.  Worth noting that at 100 connections, it works for much longer without errors.

The key part of the server and client code is below.

Client:

```
Parallel.For(1, 500, i =>
{
    var c = new ConnectedClient(i);
    c.Connect();
});

public void Connect()
{
    _tcp = new TcpClient("192.168.255.103", 666);
    _tcp.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
    _tcp.SendTimeout = 1000;
    _tcp.SendBufferSize = sendBufferSize;
    _tcp.NoDelay = true;

     _netStrm = _tcp.GetStream();
    _netStrm?.BeginRead(_byReceived, 0, 8192, DataReceived, null);
}

private void DataReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // this code receives the data, pretty boilerplate
}
```

On the server:

```
_tcpServer = new TcpServer(666, "Server");
_tcpServer.ClientConnected += TcpServerClientConnected;     

private void TcpServerClientConnected(object sender, TcpClientConnectedEventArgs e)
{
    var newClient = new ConnectedClient();
    newClient.Open(e.Client);
}

public void Open(TcpClient tcpClient) 
{
    _tcp = tcpclient;
    _tcp.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
    _tcp.SendTimeout = 1000;
    _tcp.SendBufferSize = sendBufferSize;
    _tcp.NoDelay = true;

    _messageSend = new Timer(250);
    _messageSend.Elapsed += MessageSendOnElapsed;

    _netStrm = _tcp.GetStream();
    _netStrm?.BeginRead(_byReceived, 0, ReceiveBufferSize, DataReceived, null);
}

private void MessageSendOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
{
    var data = new byte[5000];
    var packetLength = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)5000);

    using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
    {
        mem.Write(packetLength, 0, packetLength.Length);
        mem.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
       _netStrm.Write(mem.ToArray(), 0, Convert.ToInt32(mem.Length));    
    }
}
```

For the benefit of those questioning if it is possible for multiple connections into the server from the same machine, here is the output of a Console.WriteLine right before the network stream write:

```
Console.WriteLine($"sending from {_tcp.Client.LocalEndPoint} to {_tcp.Client.RemoteEndPoint}");

sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37307
sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37300
sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37186
sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37187
sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37305
sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37178
sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37184
sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37180
sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37296
sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37183
sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37297
sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37190
sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37175
sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37298
sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37185
sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37193
sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37173
sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37182
sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37174
sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37166
sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37168
sending from 192.168.255.103:666 to 192.168.255.103:37176
```

You'll see the ephemeral local client ports above (37176 etc.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167991/discussion-on-question-by-james-harcourt-c-network-stream-client-server-limits).